# why is my options overlapping with my tools

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, sculpt-mode

I've noticed that all of my tools have been overlapping with my options and i am unsure ho to move them to the right as there is more space on the right. if anyone can help that would be swell

[image]

Comment: I've only seen this happen a couple of times when I've opened a blend file in version 3.x that was created in an earlier version of Blender. I usually uncheck the Load UI option on the file selector N panel before opening it if that happens.

Answer (score 3):

Blender's UI allows *region overlap* and while it doesn't appear very often that seems to be the case here.  If so, Edit → Preferences, go to *Interface* and uncheck *Region Overlap*:

[image: Preferences showing region overlap highlighted]

This has the side effect of making the toolbar and sidebar take full height of the screen, reducing the area for the main window.

Sometimes simply toggling it off and then back on will fix your problem.