# Wired overlapping of two bar

Tags: tools

Two bars overlapped, and I could not read the info under them. Any solution?

[image]

PS: For a certain reason I have to use 2.93.5

Comment: See if https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263838/why-is-my-options-overlapping-with-my-tools/263887#263887 helps.