# Why is my viewport top bar covering itself?

Tags: 3d-view, windows

My blender project has been covering tools on the top bar and I can't figure out why. Its covering the proportional editing and snap point controls, so this is very annoying. I've tried opening and closing it, doesn't make a difference. Other projects do not have this problem. What can I do? Thank you.[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if you're in full screen?

Comment: @Starry-EyedDonut I am

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't look like the top bar is being covered. Could you clarify your question, please?

Comment: @Starry-EyedDonut Yes sorry, I see how I need to make it clearer. See the circled part on the top left? There is overlapping text because some buttons are behind other buttons, making the back ones inaccessible. And the other circle, I have a add-on search bar that is covering the snap point control and proportional editing. I'd like to keep the add-on but the only way to move it is to get rid of it. These buttons on top and the searchbar used to be slightly lower, but now the framing is off and I can't access those buttons behind them. I hope I made it clearer, sorry.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263838/why-is-my-options-overlapping-with-my-tools

Comment: Open a new Blender intances with a default scene. Go to *File > Append*, browse to the "bugged" file and append all scenes into a new fresh file. Save the new file as and continue working from there. This seems like a known issue caused by having UI scale at a value greater than 1.0